# use the caller of the wrapper function to call the inner function

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

Suppose, I have 2 contracts `A` and `B`:

```
contract A{
    function someMethod() public{
         // Something happens here
    }
}
```

And `contract B` containing its instance and its wrapper function

```
contract B{
     A instance = new A();

     function wrapper_someMethod() public{
          instance.someMethod();
     }
}
```

Now, what I want here is, whenever I call function `wrapper_someMethod()` using some address `0xABCDEF`, the call to the `someMethod()` function goes from this address only (`0xABCDEF`), and not from the `address(contract B)`.

How can I do so? Tell if there some other strategy to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a contract B is calling another contract A, `msg.sender` in contract A will **always** be B. There is no way around that.

You haven't given a lot of information. Depending on the rest of your code, here are some things to consider:

- Move `someMethod()` to contract B
- Call `someMethod()` directly, instead of through `wrapper_someMethod()`
- Use `tx.origin` in contract `someMethod()` instead of `msg.sender` (take care of your security, in most cases `tx.origin` cannot be relied on for security-critical purposes)
- Add a parameter `address _caller` to the `someMethod()` function. In `wrapper_someMethod()`, pass `msg.sender` as argument to `someMethod()`

Comment: Exactly, there are always security issues with tx.origin.

I was just wondering if that is possible. I can't change `contract A`

Looks like it isn't possible to do the way I want. 

Let me wait for a few more answers, then I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for clearing all that Jesse. Appreciate that.

Comment: Could you please look at this question too https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/what-are-the-specifications-of-ethereum-wallet-smart-contract

Answer (score 2):

I voted for Jesse's answer. For the benefit of others who come across this, a little example of the last option mentioned:

```
contract A {
    function someMethod(address sender) public{
         // Something happens here
         // proceed using "sender" the msg.sender says the transaction is for.
    }
}

contract B {

     A instance = new A();

     function wrapper_someMethod() public{
          instance.someMethod(msg.sender);
     }
}
```

This is reliable. Think in terms of `msg.sender` says "Do this, on behalf of `sender`."

Hope it helps.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. But, maybe in my case, it won't work.

I have a few doubts, let me make them clear. I'll get back if any other related doubt.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Rob, could you please look at this question too.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/what-are-the-specifications-of-ethereum-wallet-smart-contract